# Add an attribute to a grails input field field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

Am trying to add the required="true" attribute to a grails input field <g:textField. The code below are the efforts I've made to implement that but so far it's in vain.

Here is the gsp code;

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="${hasErrors(bean: user, field: 'nin', 'error')} required" id="nin">
                            <label for="nin" class="col-sm-5 control-label">
                                <g:message code="user.nin.label" default="National Identification Number (NIN)"/>
                                <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                            </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <g:textField name="nin" value="${user?.nin}" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <span class="help-inline">${hasErrors(bean: user, field: 'nin', 'error')}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

here is my jQuery code;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       let nin = $("#nin");
       nin.attr('required', true);
}
```

Ultimately am submitting a form. This div is hidden but is triggered by the value in another field. When it is triggered to display, this is when I add the required attribute. But when I submit my form with the field empty, there's no validation error, which means that the required attribute is not being picked.

Most of the resources I've read show how to do it in html, but not in grails gsp. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There's no reason that you have to use g:textField.  You could just create the input type=text yourself, and do whatever you need to there.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and its now working